# Calling biber --tool using arara: trouble with commented @ symbol within .tex file?

Tags: biber, arara

Background: I'm using Mendeley to create my .bib file and prefer to run `biber --tool` using a certain ruleset to clean up that file and retag some things.

Calling `arara -v mwe.tex` with mwe.tex contents of

```
% arara: biber: { options: [ '--tool', '--validate-datamodel', '--configfile=mwe.conf', './mwe.bib' ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./_bibertool.bib}

%@

\begin{document}

All I need to cite is Kress \textit{et al.}\supercite{Kress1988}

\end{document}
```

where mwe.bib is

```
@article{Kress1988,
  author       = {Kress, Thomas H. and Leanna, Robert M.},
  date         = {1988},
  journaltitle = {Synthesis},
  pages        = {803--805},
  title        = {{Synthesis, Stability, and Reactions of 2,6-Dichlorophenyllithium}},
  abstract     = {{irrelevant abstract comes here}},
}
```

and mwe.conf is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <output_indent>2</output_indent>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

will end in error:

```
PS <PATH> arara -v mwe.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'mwe.tex' (size: 385 bytes, last modified: 02/13/2020
09:18:19), please wait.

-----------------------------------------------------------------
(Biber) The Biber reference management software
-----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO - This is Biber 2.14 running in TOOL mode
INFO - Config file is 'mwe.conf'
INFO - Logfile is './mwe.bib.blg'
INFO - Globbing data source './mwe.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source './mwe.bib' to ./mwe.bib
INFO - Globbing data source 'mwe'
INFO - Globbed data source 'mwe' to mwe
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file './mwe.bib'
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source './mwe.bib'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mwe'
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source './mwe.tex'
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\mail\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_mwP6\mwe.tex_13692.utf8, line 16, syntax error: at end of input, expected "@"
INFO - ERRORS: 1

--------------------------------------------------------- FAILURE

Total: 1.72 seconds
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar -v mwe.tex
```

If the `%@` line is removed from the .tex file, compilation will work fine. Using an up-to-date TeX Live 2019. Seems to me that `%@` is *somehow* parsed by arara, *somehow* causing fancy-character trouble with `biber --tool`?

I wasn't able to intercept the .utf8 file from the Temp folder before it's deleted. However, I was able to intercept an .utf8 file generated from my production .bib file as it's significantly larger in size. Couldn't find any syntax error where Biber reports to have found one; When I copied the contents over to mwe.bib and used this file within `\addbibresource`, I was able to compile the document (omitting `biber --tool`) without trouble. Thanks for your input...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a file `bibertool.yaml`

```
!config
# Arara, the cool TeX automation tool
# Copyright (c) 2018, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda 
# All rights reserved.
#
# This rule is part of arara.
identifier: bibertool
name: BiberTool
authors:
- Marco Daniel
- Paulo Cereda
commands:
- name: The Biber reference management software
  command: >
    @{
        return getCommand('biber', options);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

by just changing the line

```
return getCommand('biber', options, getBasename(file));
```

and fixing the identifier from the original `biber.yaml`. Saving this file as `~/arara/rules/bibertool` and running `arara` on

```latex
% arara: bibertool: { options: [ '--tool', '--validate-datamodel', '--configfile=mwe.conf', './mwe.bib' ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./_bibertool.bib}

%@

\begin{document}

All I need to cite is Kress \textit{et al.}\supercite{Kress1988}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

produces the desired output, including the `_bibertool.bib` file

```latex
@article{Kress1988,
  author       = {Kress, Thomas H. and Leanna, Robert M.},
  date         = {1988},
  journaltitle = {Synthesis},
  pages        = {803--805},
  title        = {{Synthesis, Stability, and Reactions of 2,6-Dichlorophenyllithium}},
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to both @Ulrike Fischer and you, very helpful! I could swear that my original method was still working before an update in the second half of 2019. But I understand now what went wrong... Please consider the 'accepted answer' as shared between you two!

Answer (score 5):

It breaks for me with and without the `%@` as my test file contains other crap too.

Your first call to biber is wrong, you are passing to it two file arguments: `biber --tool mwe.bib mwe` and that means that it tries to process two source files. At first as wanted the bib-file:

```
 Looking for bibtex format file './mwe.bib'
```

But then is also tries to resolve the request for the `mwe` without extensions and finds the tex file:

```
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mwe'
 ....
INFO - Found BibTeX data source './mwe.tex'
```

When trying to make sense of the tex file is fails at the @ but probably lots of other input can trigger errors here - a tex file simply isn't a bib-file.

I don't see in the arara documentation a way to run biber without the second file argument so probably you need a new arara rule.